# I keep getting this error and I cant fix it: error CS0161: 'Program.MathMinWhole(int, int)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, error-handling

I'm trying to recreate the Math.Min(); built-in feature of C# but I keep running into this error when I try to actually save it to a variable

Here's my code;

```
using System;

namespace ReviewMethodCallsAndInput

{

  class Program

 {

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int whichNumber = MathMinWhole(3, 4);
}

static int MathMinWhole(int numberOne, int numberTwo)
{

int finalNumber = numberOne <= numberTwo ? numberOne : numberTwo;


  }
```

}
}

Comment: Where is the return?

Comment: A method that states to return an int should _return int_ in your case _return finalNumber;_

Comment: You have no `return` statement in your `MathMinWhole` method - and since this method is not a `void` method - it must return a value or throw an exception in any code path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement at the end of your method:

```
return finalNumber;
```